# IOException when using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to exec "stat" on Android?

Tags: android, linux, stat

The key code is:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stat", null, file);
```

and I get the IOexception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [stat] Working Directory: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Environment: null
```

I noticed that this problem happens only on some Android 5.x devices, and 6.x devices work fine. And when I test "ls" command it works fine for all my devices.
What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Command "stat" is incorrect.If you want to open explorer use "start"

Comment: stat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file(in win7 or above)

Comment: it's a linux command.Android is running in linux,so it should be recognized